# What automatic decode routines does Apache+PHP use?

Tags: php, apache

While looking over the doc's for [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) I came across this note:

> The superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST
>   are already decoded. Using urldecode()
>   on an element in $_GET or $_REQUEST
>   could have unexpected and dangerous
>   results.

This is the reason why a get variable with the value of `%26` ends up being `&`.  Are there any other auto-magical decode routines other than `urldecode()`?  Perhaps decoding that is only done because of configuration or negotiation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GET parameter decoding works actually in this sequence:

- explode(`"&"`, $QUERY_STRING)
- strtok(`"="`) to split names from value
- `urldecode()` on name *and* value
- `strtr(".", "_", $name)` - non-alphanumeric characters mostly stripped from var names (a GET parameter &x.y= becomes $_GET["x`_`y"])
- expanding of `[] array` names
- `addslashes()` on values if magic quotes were enabled - this is the only part that's configurable

When decoding POST parameters in multipart/form-data a charset= could be set individually for each field. But I have a hunch that PHP doesn't respect that.

That is all. AFAIK

Comment: +1 very good.  Do you have any references?  The php c++ file that performs these actions would be awesome.

Comment: I think it's mostly in http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/php_variables.c?revision=298241&view=markup - search for "Remove leading spaces from cookie names,"

Answer (score 1):

While no longer really an issue in the later builds of PHP, GET POST & COOKIES used to have quotes automatically escaped... See here for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php